# aa-genprof will not scan to create profiles!

Tags: apparmor

I'm currently messing around with apparmor and creating profiles etc.
When I run aa-genprof and try to scan I am presented with following error.

ERROR: Include file /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser not found

I get the same error regardless of what executable I give.

Running ubuntu 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you should install [`lightdm` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=lightdm_chromium-browser&mode=exactfilename&suite=artful&arch=any) to get this file
with `sudo apt-get install lightdm`.

Below is a clue:

```
$ dpkg -S lightdm_chromium-browser
lightdm: /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser
```